# How to stop this recursive method after 2 iterations

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to get this method to only run twice. I've tried to pass a counter as a parameter like so, but it does not appear to be working.

```
@Override
public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(int counter, IaasService iaas) {
    int counter = 0; 
    counter+=2; 
    try { 
        iaas = CloudLoader.loadNodes("C:\\Users\\Tom\\git\\dissect-cf-examp‌les\\PM.xml");
    } 
    catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return createCloudAndReturnWithIt(); 
}
```

Comment: pass a counter and increment until desired value is reached - if only doing twice, then does not realyl seem to fit the recursive pattern

Comment: I've tried passing a counter and it doesn't work

Comment: @SwitchCase Show us what you've tried

Comment: public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt() {
  int counter = 0;
  counter+=2;
 try {
   iaas = CloudLoader.loadNodes("C:\\Users\\Tom\\git\\dissect-cf-examples\\PM.xml");
  } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return createCloudAndReturnWithIt(); 
  

  }

Comment: That's not going to work because you don't pass it as a parameter for the method. Each time you call it, the counter will be set back to 0, and nothing will happen.

Comment: @UnknowableIneffible what would you suggest?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter. I'll write it as an answer, so you can look at what I suggest.

Comment: @SwitchCase: when you update the problem, edit the changes into the original question text.  Leaving it in a comment makes it hard to track (two different places) and hard to read (comments don't format code decently).

Comment: @UnknowableIneffible I have passed it

Comment: @Prune never asked a question on here :P thank you

Comment: You didn't pass it as a parameter in the code you posted in the comments.

Comment: @UnknowableIneffible my bad, changed it now

Comment: If you pass `IaasService iaas` as parameter why isn't it used in the method body?

Comment: This is not recursion, Your returning a different method. Java method differentiate based on method signature i.e. different parameter types equal different methods. eg: Signature `createCloudAndReturnWithIt(int counter, IaasService iaas)` vs `return createCloudAndReturnWithIt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with recursion the first thing you should think about is how you are going to exit the recursive loop. Once you have a way to exit the loop you just need to call itself with some sort of iteration. Below all I have done is added a ternary to your return checking if the counter is less than or equal to 0. If it is less than or equal to 0, we return iaas, otherwise we return a call to the same method decrementing the counter. In this version of the loop, it will iterate from n times, n being the counter. Below I added default behavior in the overloaded version:

```
public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(int counter, IaasService iaas) 
{
    try 
    { 
      iaas = CloudLoader.loadNodes("C:\\Users\\Tom\\git\\dissect-cf-examp‌les\\PM.xml");
    } 
    catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e)  
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return (counter <= 0) ? iaas : createCloudAndReturnWithIt(--counter, iaas); 
}

public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(IaasService iaas) 
{
     return createCloudAndReturnWithIt(2, iaas);
}
```

[Here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) is some documentation on recursion in Java. If you never intend on allowing users of this the ability to iterate more than twice, consider making the method that accepts a counter argument private, package private, or protected, depending on your use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you don't ever stop your program when your counter hits 2. Also, you keep reseting the value of the counter each time, so it doesn't get anywhere.

To get this recursive method to stop after two iterations, using the counter that you attempted to use, you would have to pass the counter as a parameter, not set it equal to 0 each time, and have a condition to check whether or not it is time to stop recursing. Altogether, it would look like this:

```
public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(int counter) {
    //you would always run this with counter = 0
    if(counter == 2){
         //return whatever IaaSService object you want this method to create
    }
    //Your other code to make whatever you need to happen happen.
    counter++;
    return createCloudAndReturnWithIt(counter);    
}
```

This will make your recursion stop after two calls, but as user Scary Wombat pointed out in the comments, if you are only recursing twice every time, it might be better just to iterate through this code instead of using recursion.

Also, generally speaking, when you are using recursion, make sure you have a base case, otherwise the recursion will never end until it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Method overload looks like the best approach to your problem.

```
// this should be the first method called
@Override
public IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(IaasService iaas) {
   // the entry to the recursion, start the count at 0
   return createCloudAndReturnWithIt(0, iaas);
} 


// for improved efficiency this method should only be called by 
// this method so give it a private visibility
// @Override <-- what are you overriding?
private IaaSService createCloudAndReturnWithIt(int counter, IaasService iaas) { 
   try { 
      iaas = CloudLoader.loadNodes("C:\\Users\\Tom\\git\\dissect-cf-examp‌les\\PM.xml");
   } 

   catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {      
     e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 

   // the key is to end the recursion with iaas after two iterations
   return counter == 1 ? iaas : createCloudAndReturnWithIt(++count, iaas); 
}
```